# Why is the Java code in JSP generating an error?

Tags: java, jsp, exception

I'm trying to input some java code in my jsp however the following exception is being generated :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /Home.jsp(31,8) PWC6203: Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed
```

My jsp contains an if statement and will check data. If it matches, some html code is displayed, otherwise, another code is displayed

```
<% String username = session.getAttribute("loggedIn").toString();
               String actual = "${message.message}";
               if(username.equals(actual)){%>
                <div style="background-color:#fff380;"> 
                ...
                </div>
            <%} else { %>
                <div> 
                ...
                </div>
            <%}%>
```

Does anyone know why this type of error is being generated please? thanks a lot

Comment: `String actual = "${message.message}";`. AFAIK EL does not work with scriptlets.

Comment: @Samir - how is that question relevant?  It doesn't mention this error at all.

Comment: @HarryJoy is there another way to be able to get the message then? 'message' is one of a list of messages and the html is looping through these messages using the core taglib. I've tried to get  the message directly from the session but its giving me errors

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423252/teamcity-scripting-elements-jspdeclaration-jspexpression-jspscriptlet-are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sciptlet usage has probably been configured invalid (see http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=548). And this choice was a wise choice, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs anymore. Use the JSTL and the EL:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${loggedIn == message.message}">
        ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Moreover, even if scriplet was valid, you can't use the JSP EL inside scriptlet code.

Comment: I would like to perform the equality with a variable stored in the session. Is there a way in el to get it? because i'm getting it using java code and its still giving me errors

Comment: The code in my answer does it. The EL first looks for an attribute in the page scope, then in request scope, then in session scope, then is application scope. If you want to specifically target the session scope, use sessionScope.loggedIn. Find a tutorial about the JSP EL, because you really need to master it when using JSPs.